Factoring $(1+x+...+x^n)^2 - x^n$

Factorize $(1+x+x^2+...+x^n)^2-x^n$

I know that $(1+x+x^2+...+x^n)^2 = 1+2x+3x^2+...+(n+1)x^n+...+2x^{2n-1}+x^{2n}$
So $(1+x+x^2+...+x^n)^2 - x^n = 1+2x+3x^2+...+nx^n+...+2x^{2n-1}+x^{2n}$
This is equal to $(1+x+x^2+...+x^{n+1})(1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1})$. I see why this is true (sum of coeff), but is there an intuitive way of deriving the last step?

Maybe consider the first term as a geometric sum and factorise the numerator of $\left(\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\right)^2 - x^n$?

For clarification, would this be intuitive while not expanding everything:
$$\begin{align*}
\left(1+x+\cdots+x^n\right)^2 - x^n
&= \left(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}\right)\left(1+x+\cdots+x^n\right) + x^n\left(1+x+\cdots+x^n\right) - x^n\
&= \left(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}\right)\left(1+x+\cdots+x^n\right) + x^n\left(x+\cdots+x^n\right)\
&= \left(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}\right)\left(1+x+\cdots+x^n\right) + x^{n+1}\left(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}\right)\
&= \left(1+x+\cdots+x^n+x^{n+1}\right) \left(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}\right)\
\end{align*}$$?

Yes, thank you! I was looking for a way to derive the final factorization, and this makes sense.

Recall that from the geometric series summation formula,
$$1+x+\dots+x^n = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x - 1}$$
So,
$$(1+x+...+x^n)^2 - x^n$$
$$= \left(\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x - 1}\right)^2 - x^n$$
$$= \frac{(x^{n+1}-1)^2 - x^n(x-1)^2}{(x - 1)^2}$$
$$= \frac{x^{2n+2}-2x^{n+1}+1 - x^{n+2} + 2x^{n+1} - x^n}{(x - 1)^2}$$
$$= \frac{x^{2n+2} - x^{n+2} - x^n + 1}{(x - 1)^2}$$
$$= \frac{(x^{n+2} - 1)(x^{n} - 1)}{(x - 1)^2}$$
$$= \frac{x^{n+2} - 1}{x-1} \cdot \frac{x^{n} - 1}{x - 1}$$
$$= (1+x+\dots+x^{n+1})(1+x+\dots+x^{n-1})$$
where the last step uses the same summation formula for the beginning, with different maximum exponents.

When $x^m=1$ and $x\neq 1$,
$$x^{m-1}+x^{m-2}+...+x+1=0.$$
We will use this idea to show that the roots of $p(x)=(1+x+...+x^n)^2-x^n$ are roots of unity.
If $x^n=1,$ and $x\neq1$, then $p(x)=(x^n)^2-x^n=1^2-1=0.$ Therefore, $\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}|\,p(x).$
If $x^{n+2}=1$ and $x\neq1$, then
$$p(x)=(-x^{n+1})^2-x^n\\=(-x^{-1})^2-x^{-2}=0.$$
Therefore, $\frac{x^{n+2}-1}{x-1}|\, p(x).$
By degree calculation we conclude that $p(x)=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\frac{x^{n+2}-1}{x-1}.$
